# rsync with --remove-sent-files option and open files

Tags: linux, file, rsync

Every minute I need to copy recorded files from 3 servers to one data storage. I don't need to save original files - data processing is outside of all of them.

But when i use option `--remove-sent-files`, rsync sends and removes not finished (not closed) files.

I've tried to prevent sending these open files with `lsof` and `--exclude-from`, but it seems, that rsync does not unserstand full paths in exlude list:

```
--exclude-from=FILE     read exclude >>patterns<< from FILE

lsof | grep /projects/recordings/.\\+\\.\\S\\+ -o | sort | uniq
/projects/recordings/<uid>/<path>/2012-07-16 13:24:32.646970-<id>.WAV
```

So, the script looks like:

```
# get open files in src dir and put them into rsync.exclude file
lsof | grep /projects/recordings/.\\+\\.\\S\\+ -o | sort | uniq > /tmp/rsync.exclude
# sync without these files
/usr/bin/rsync -raz --progress --size-only --remove-sent-files --exclude-files=/tmp/rsync.excldude /projects/recordings/ site.com:/var/www/storage/recordings/
# change owner
ssh storage@site.com chown -hR storage:storage /var/www/storage/recordings
```

So, may be i should try another tool? Or why rsync does not listen to exludes?

Comment: Your version of rsync may need the spaces in the file names escaped, i.e, /projects/recordings/<uid>/<path>/2012-07-16\ 13:24:32.646970-<id>.WAV. So something like `filewithspaces | sed 's/ /\\ /g'`

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this helps you, but here's my solution to only rsync files which are not currently being written to. I use it for tshark captures, writing to a new file every N seconds with the -a flag (e.g. tshark -i eth0 -a duration:30 -w /foo/bar/caps). Watch out for that tricky rsync, the order of the include and exclude is important, and if we want sub-directories we need to include "*/".

-G

```
$save_path=/foo/bar/
$delay_between_syncs=30
while true;
do
 sleep $delay_between_syncs

 # Calculate which files are currently open (i.e. the ones currently being written to)
 # and avoid uploading it. This is to ensure that when we process files on the server, they
 # are complete.
 echo "" > /tmp/include_list.txt
 for i in `find $save_path/ -type f`
  do
    op=`fuser $i`
    if [ "$op" == "" ]
            then
                    #echo [+] $i is good for upload, will add it list.
                    c=`echo $i | sed 's/.*\///g'`
                    echo $c >> /tmp/include_list.txt
    fi
  done

 echo [+] Syncing...
 rsync -rzt --include-from=/tmp/include_list.txt --include="*/" --exclude \* $save_path user@server:/home/backup/foo/
 echo [+] Sunk... 

done
```

Answer (score 0):

rsync the files, then remove the ones that have been rsync'd by capturing the list of transferred files, and then removing only the transferred files that are not currently open. Rsync figures out what files to transfer when it gets to the directory, so your solution was bound to fail later even if it worked at first, when a newly opened file (since rsync started) was not in the exclude list.

An alternate approach would be to do a

find dir -type f -name pattern -mmin +10 | xargs -i rsync -aP {} dest:/path/to/backups